# Raspberry Pi 4 Model B Project: IoT Parking Apps with Car Plate Recognition for Smart City using Node Red

Tags: pi-4, arduino, nodered

recently I found a project that involves using Raspberry Pi and Arduino Mega Board to create a Car Plate Recognition system but I am stuck with connecting the pins as I am not a professional in using Raspberry Pi and Arduino Mega Board, I hope that someone can help me with identifying the whole diagram on how to connect the pins for the project. Thanks

I will include the file here: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1C__YittSEo8ufVL7_Rolh3VZkYSS4qmY?usp=sharing

Note: the page of the prototype that I am referring to is on the page 42 (Figure 4.2).

There will be some detailed picture starting from page 42 as well

The source codes (Node Red) for the Raspberry Pi is available from the page 51 until page 56.

Comment: Hi jsotola, actually it's the connection from Raspberry pi -> Bread Board, Arduino Mega -> Bread Board and finally all of the components are plugged into the bread board because I tried to connect it all together but the instructions are not clear in the document so I need help with it

Comment: There are some differences between my setup with the setup above because I was using Raspberry pi 4 instead of Raspberry Pi 3 and the Arduino board above is Arduino Uno and mine is Arduino Mega 2560, so the layout of the pins different for both of the boards.

Comment: Page 42, I will also update the post as well.

Comment: there is no Raspberry Pi in fig. 4.2 ... what is your Raspberry Pi specific question?

Comment: Sorry, it's on the page 44 (figure 4.5), as I am not sure plug on which pin on the raspberry pi.

Comment: But the overall setup of the project on connecting the pins is still a major issue to me.

Comment: Ok, sure. As I just asked another question on the Arduino Stack Exchange. So, lets focus on connecting the pins between the Raspberry Pi and breadboard.

Comment: There are 3 cables on the Raspberry Pi (Figure 4.5) and I believe that the 3 cables are connected to the 3 cables to the top right corner of the breadboard (Figure 4.2). But my breadboard is 8.5*5.5 cm (400 holes) instead of 16.5*5.5 cm (830 holes), so the layout is different for me.

Comment: how would the size of the breadboard make any difference? ... fig 4.2 shows only an LED with a resistor anywhere near the right end of the breadboard ... figure out which pin connects to what by analyzing the program

Comment: Oh, Ok. Thanks for clarifying. I will update the post and the code starts from page 51 until page 56.