# Looking for project suggestion which uses Raspberry Pi to create IoT Parking Apps with Car Plate Recognition

Tags: pi-4, tutorial

I would like to know is there any complete license plate recognition projects which are using Raspberry Pi 4 model B as I can't find any complete relevant projects with full source codes or tutorials attached. I hope that you guys can help me out.

What I need is a project which uses image recognition to recognize the plate number and a simple mobile app to make payment (Something like MIT App Inventor to create a dummy app is fine).

Here's a video that I want to create: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jAA92w44kcM

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Raspberry Pi 4 Model B Project: IoT Parking Apps with Car Plate Recognition for Smart City using Node Red](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/133384/raspberry-pi-4-model-b-project-iot-parking-apps-with-car-plate-recognition-for)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I have not personally tried this project, a search brings up this website: https://iotdesignpro.com/projects/real-time-license-plate-recognition-using-raspberry-pi-and-python. Although it seems the tutorial writer used a Pi 3B+, the project uses OpenCV and Tesseract which should be compatible with the Pi 4. It also fully explains the installation process. If you are using picamera, (unfortunately the tutorial is heavily reliant on picamera but it should be not too hard to modify) it should work for your purposes.